# wcf rest end point not found from remote computer

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, hosting

I have Wcf rest service.
I host it in console application.
when I try to access the service from my local computer it works but when I try from remote 
computer the service is not found.
here is the code:

service definition:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInstagramCallbackService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "url/?hub.mode={mode}&hub.challenge={challenge}&hub.verify_token={token}")]       
     string CheckServiceAvailability(string mode, string challenge, string token);
}

public class InstagramCallbackService : IInstagramCallbackService
{
    public string CheckServiceAvailability(string mode, string challenge, string token)
    {
        return challenge;
    }
}
```

hosting:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(InstagramCallbackService),new Uri[]{});

WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None);

ServiceEndpoint endPoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
    ContractDescription.GetContract(
        typeof(InstagramCallbackService)), binding, new EndpointAddress(
            "http://127.0.0.1:6064/InstagramCallbackService"));

WebHttpBehavior webBehavior = new WebHttpBehavior();
endPoint.Behaviors.Add(webBehavior);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(endPoint);
host.Open();
Console.WriteLine("ready");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is a local address. It's like saying `localhost` or "this computer". You can't hit `127.0.0.1` from another computer, because `127.0.0.1` from another computer would just be *that* computer. Surely your machine has other addresses you can use though no? Try `ipconfig` from the command line.

Comment: Are you using `127.0.0.1`? because that's only visible from the computer you're current using. You should at least have an additional `169.254.x.x` address that is visible across your local network.